# Issue In Installing Azure IoT Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am trying to install azure-iot-sdk python but according to but when I am trying to build my device I have to face the crash error at 92% as mentioned below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
If someone knows about the alternative to avoid this error, 
your suggestion will be much valuable

For tutorial reference, mentioned below are the site links which I am using

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md#linux

Comment: I'd open an issue on Github to get faster answer on this.

Comment: Thanks for you help Laurent,  I ll surely get it done.